# serialization/de-serializationa complex class in flutter?

Tags: sharedpreferences, flutter

I have a complex class like below

```
class BoardState {
  List<List<int>> tiles;
  final Point lastTileAdded;
  final int dimension;
  static int nextNum = 2;
  static int score = 0;
...
//lot of other stuffs
}
```

I have to store the `BoardState` with `shared_preferences`, I figured out that I should serialize this to a String and back but `Json.encode()` is not able to encode such complex class for me, I couldn't find any way to do that? is there any advice? sample code?

Comment: https://flutter.io/json/

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I am having another trouble (version solving failed.) for installing `json_annotation`  and on the other hand I don't know how to implement manual JSON implementation specially for that 2d array `tiles` in `BoardState` can you please provide a sample code for implementing Manual `toJson()` implementation?